# Cant we use c to develop windows phone 7.5 apps?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

My question is can we use c++ in code behind to develop Windows Phone 7.5 and above apps ?

Comment: Why does the title say C, and the question body say C++? Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I don't think it's possible. Look at these links, maybe they can help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402526(v=vs.92).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/the-ersoy-experiment-in-windows-phone-7-development-using-xna/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible on Windows Phone 8, but not on anything below that.